# How to unmute the sounds in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Sorry for my English..I have a code for two buttons to mute and unmute sounds..when I click to mute the sounds, it works but when I click to the other button to make the sounds to play it doesn't worked..any help?

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

speakerb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speaker2sound);
speakerb2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speaker2sound);
var channel2:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var clicktoPlay:Boolean = true;


function speaker2sound(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (clicktoPlay==true){
         var snd2:Sound = new Sound;
         snd2.load(new URLRequest("shakeup.wav"));
         clicktoPlay=false;
         channel2 = snd2.play();
         speakerb1.visible=true;
         speakerb2.visible=false;
         SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
    }

    if (clicktoPlay==false){
         clicktoPlay=true;
         speakerb2.visible=true;
         speakerb1.visible=false;
         SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
    }
    clicktoPlay =!clicktoPlay;
}

channel2.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundfin);

function soundfin(event:Event):void{ 
    clicktoPlay=false; 
    speakerb1.visible=true;
    speakerb2.visible=false;
}
```

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that you're doing some weird stuff with your `clicktoPlay` variable. You check to see if it's true, then you set it to false, then you check to see if it's false (which it will ALWAYS be, because if it was originally true, you set it to false). Then after all of that, you're toggling it again.

Comment: yes but when I click again and it's false then I make the clicktoPlay true..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working with a few small changes:

```
speakerb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speaker2sound);
speakerb2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, speaker2sound);
var channel2:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var clicktoPlay:Boolean = true;
var snd2:Sound;

function speaker2sound(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (clicktoPlay==true){
        if(!snd2){
            snd2 = new Sound();
            snd2.load(new URLRequest("Kalimba.mp3"));
            channel2 = snd2.play();
        }
        speakerb1.visible=true;
        speakerb2.visible=false;
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
    }
    else {
        speakerb2.visible=true;
        speakerb1.visible=false;
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
    }
    clicktoPlay =!clicktoPlay;
}

channel2.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundfin);

function soundfin(event:Event):void{ 
    clicktoPlay=false; 
    speakerb1.visible=true;
    speakerb2.visible=false;
}

channel2.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,soundfin);

function soundfin(event:Event):void{ 
    clicktoPlay=false; 
    speakerb1.visible=true;
    speakerb2.visible=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marcela says, try taking out the line "clicktoPlay =!clicktoPlay;" and see if it works.
The way your code is now, until "soundfin" is called, clicktoPlay will remain true no matter how often speaker2sound is called.